# How to access variables across namespaces in thrift

Tags: c++, namespaces, thrift

Let's say I have two files

## Something.thrift

```
namespace cpp something
struct Something { ... }
```

## Marvelous.thrift

```
include "Something.thrift"
namespace cpp marvelous
struct IncludingSomething {
    1: required something::Something;
}
```

Here the scope resolution operator is not recognized,  how do I access `Something` from `Marvelous.thrift`?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Thrift include two files with same name?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32563197/thrift-include-two-files-with-same-name)

Answer (score 1):

Using the `dot` operator.  So like this

```
include "Something.thrift"
namespace cpp marvelous
struct IncludingSomething {
    1: required something.Something;
}
```